# Viewing statistics on self hosted site from Android WordPress app

Tags: android

I did / do have a WordPress hosted blog (with statistics working fine). I've now set-up a self hosted blog and have paid for an off-site redirect from WordPress to my new blog. That all works fine.

If I log onto my self hosted admin page I can see the sites statistics, but I'm asked to log in again, this is odd, but I do get to see the statistics.

However, when I'm using the WordPress for Android  (1.3.7) application and I log onto my self hosted site I see no statistics unless I go to the year view. This seems to then show me the statistics from the WordPress site, but not my self hosted site.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is off topic, IMO. This has less to do with WordPress than with two third party applications (Android app, and WP Stats). The WordPress for Android bug tracker is at http://android.trac.wordpress.org/ I think you'd get much more help if you searched for your issue there; if you can't find it, report a bug. Voting to close.

Comment: I just tested this with my own site (running a self-hosted WP site integrated with the WordPress.com stats plug-in).  I'm running in to the same problem, which tells me it's an *application* issue ... either on the stats side or the Android App side ... both of which are products of [Automattic](http://www.automattic.com) and better addressed through **a direct conversation** with them, their **support forums**, or the **WordPress for Android bug tracker** as referenced by *@John P Bloch*.  Vote to close as OT.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is just an issue with the application, not with your wordpress installation.  I suppose that could be good or bad news.  Regardless, I would suggest that you submit the bug to the application developers because if you are running into this problem, the chances are so are several other people, though you may be the first one to point it out.